# rtrim error in oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have these tables declared in oracle. referencias has loaded data and i want to load some attributes in envase. If i run th following insert , i get an 01722 invalid number oracle . What would be the rtrim format to avoid the error?

```
CREATE TABLE envase (
referencia VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
descripcion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
precio number(9,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ENVASE PRIMARY KEY (referencia)
);

CREATE TABLE referencias( 
producto      VARCHAR2(50),
codBarras     VARCHAR2(15),
tipoProducto  VARCHAR2(20),
marcaCafetera VARCHAR2(10),
modelCafetera VARCHAR2(12),
tipoCafe      VARCHAR2(10),
varietal      VARCHAR2(30),
procedencia   VARCHAR2(15),
tueste        VARCHAR2(10),
proceso       VARCHAR2(12),
envase        VARCHAR2(15),
precio        VARCHAR2(10),
stock         NUMBER(5),
min_stock     NUMBER(5),
max_stock     NUMBER(5),
coste         VARCHAR(10),
proveedor     VARCHAR2(35),
CIF           VARCHAR2(10),
Comercial     VARCHAR2(90),
email         VARCHAR2(60),
telefono      NUMBER(9), 
cuentaBank    VARCHAR2(30),
TipoVia       VARCHAR2(10),
nombreVia     VARCHAR2(30),
portal        VARCHAR2(3),
bloque        NUMBER(1),
escalera      NUMBER(2),
planta        VARCHAR2(7),
puerta        VARCHAR2(1),
CP            NUMBER(5),
localidad     VARCHAR2(45),
pais          VARCHAR2(45)
);


INSERT INTO envase
(referencia,descripcion,precio)
SELECT DISTINCT
codBarras, envase,TO_NUMBER(RTRIM(precio,' €'),'999999999.99')
FROM referencias;
```

Comment: What are some examples of the data in the precio column?  Do they all start with the euro character, or might they start with something else?

Comment: Although technically MySQL is owned by the Oracle company too, `Oracle` in general (and in the tag you used) refers to the Oracle DBMS. So please use either `Oracle` or `MySQL` in the tags to make unambiguously clear which one you mean.

Comment: @PlanItMichael: If he's got data starting with the Euro symbol, that'll be the problem - RTRIM only rips off the trailing occurances .. he'll need to use LTRIM to catch any leading characters. (probably easier to use TRANSLATE at that point ;) )

Comment: @Ditto Good reasoning, although the question doesn't contain any example of an actual value in `precio`, so your guess is just a guess and this question is a poor question. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol: True enough ;) (hence I use the words "probably" and "if" .. until he posts more samples, any answer's going to remain a bit of guesswork - although the options are somewhat narrowed due to the information he has provided.

Comment: @PlanItMichael  this is an example of the data in precio column.  4.10 € , 34.99 €, 34.00 €

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest simply leaving off the format mask from the "to_number" and allowing Oracle to figure out the number format:

This works just fine for me:

```
select to_number(rtrim('4.10 €', ' €')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared it as:

```
precio number(9,2) NOT NULL,
```

NUMBER(9,2)

which means, 9 digits .. 2 of which are decimals.
Maximum number:  9999999.99

However, you number pattern appears to be:

```
codBarras, envase,TO_NUMBER(RTRIM(precio,' €'),'999999999.99')
```

Which has 11 digits, 2 of which as decimals.

I assume you have data coming in larger than 10 million, which blows it up during insert.

Change you initial create for envase to 11,2, not 9,2 and try it again?

```
CREATE TABLE envase (
referencia VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
descripcion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
precio number(11,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ENVASE PRIMARY KEY (referencia)
);
```

[edit]
although when I test it, I get 
`ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`
;) so it might be something else or a combination of issues ... 
[/edit]